# Polly timeout before execute is called

Tags: polly

I have a policy which I execute like this:

```
_logger.LogDebug($"Got the policy for {tenant.TenantCode}");
policy.Execute(
        () =>
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"Calling _domainEventDLA.GetOldestEvent {tenant.TenantCode}");
            domainEvent = _domainEventDLA.GetOldestEvent(tenant);
            _logger.LogDebug($"Calling _domainEventDLA.GetOldestEvent {tenant.TenantCode}");
        }
    );
```

I have a timeout set to 3 seconds and I get the polly timeout exception. The method in the execute takes less than 100 milliseconds.

In the log I see the first log line (Got the policy for...) and the next thing logged is the timeout exception 3 seconds later.  I never see the log line in the execute before the actual method call (Calling _domainEventDLA ...).

This is the timeout policy:

```
var timeoutPolicy = Policy
                .Timeout(3, timeoutStrategy: TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic,
                onTimeout: (context, timespan, task) =>
                {
                    _logger.LogError(
                        $"A database timeout occured after {timespan.TotalSeconds} seconds, for tenant {tenant.TenantCode}.");
                });
```

This is a multi-threaded application so other threads may be using the same policy.

Any ideas?

Comment: All Polly policy logic is thread safe in itself, so re-use of a policy instance across multiple threads is not an issue.  You can execute concurrently through the same TimeoutPolicy, and the timeouts will be independently correctly enforced.

Comment: Probably you are experiencing thread starvation. As the Polly project [documents here](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#additional-notes-pessimistic-timeout-for-sync-executions), synchronous pessimistic timeout comes at the expense of spinning off the executed delegate on another thread. Thread starvation can occur in any highly parallelised application. Looks as if your code is experiencing thread starvation when starting the task of the executed delegate. See the recommendations in the Polly doco linked about limiting parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are experiencing thread starvation. The Polly project gives the [following explanation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#additional-notes-pessimistic-timeout-for-sync-executions) about the use of synchronous pessimistic timeout policy in the case of high parallelism:

> For synchronous executions, the ability of the calling thread to 'walk away' from an otherwise un-timeout-able action comes at a cost: to allow the current thread to walk away, the policy **executes the user delegate as a Task on a ThreadPool thread**.
>
> Because of this cost *we do not recommend pessimistic synchronous TimeoutPolicy in scenarios where the number of concurrent requests handled is potentially high or unbounded.* In such high/unbounded scenarios, that cost (effectively doubling the number of threads used) may be very expensive.
>
> We recommend pessimistic synchronous TimeoutPolicy in conjunction with explicitly limiting the parallelism of calls on that codepath. Options to control parallelism include:
>
> - using Polly BulkheadPolicy (which is a parallism-throttle) upstream of the Timeout policy
> - using a concurrency-limiting TaskScheduler upstream of the Timeout policy
> - using a circuit-breaker policy upstream of the TimeoutPolicy, with the circuit-breaker configured to break if too many downstream calls are timing out. The prevents an excessive number of calls being put through to the downstream system (and blocking threads) when it is timing out
> - any other in-built parallelism controls of the calling environment.

It looks as if your code is experiencing thread starvation: it seems likely that when scheduling the task of the executed delegate, a thread is not available from the ThreadPool to execute it before the timeout occurs.

Thread starvation can occur in any highly parallelised application, of course.  Understanding peak load for your application and choosing whether to limit parallelism before unpredictable events start occurring (as [discussed on the Polly blog](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Transient-fault-handling-and-proactive-resilience-engineering#bulkhead-as-load-shedding)) can be a useful practice.